# IntelliJ missing DataSource file?

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I am using intelliJ and I read that " in /grails-app/conf/ directory, you’ll find a file named DataSource.groovy." I need that file in order to make my computer a local database for storing info ,well I can only see in my itelliJ in that directory : resourses,logback and groovy file.So how can I make my computer database from the DataSource file

Answer (score 1):

DataSource.groovy was used in Grails 1.x and 2.x, but isn't used in Grails 3+. In Grails 3 those settings go in `application.yml` (or `application.groovy`). The syntax is the same as it was except that now the `dataSource` block is included with the rest of the configuration in one file. The syntax is described [in the reference docs](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSource).

Answer (score -1):

**For Grails 3.x :**

If you are using Grails 3.x there is no `DataSource.groovy` file.

You need to add DB configuration in `application.yml` file.

**For Grails 1.x and 2.x :**

when you create the Grail's project, grail's create all the necessary  config files for you.

When you open project from IDE you can see all the configuration files generated under the

```
app_name/grails-app/conf
```

There exists an **"DataSource.groovy"** where you can specify your DB details according to environment.

like below :

```
// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
        }
```

You can set Database connection parameters according to environment.

As you said you need **your local machine to act as Database so you need to first install the required Database(like mysql, mongoDB etc.)** on your local machine and specify its connection parameter in "DataSource.groovy".

Once you are done done with configuration then you can start creating controller and services according to your needs.

You can read through the "Grails CookBook" for your application development as they have given simple examples to understand.

Reference : http://grails.asia/grails-example-applications

Comment: He's using Grails 3, which you can tell because there's a logback config file

Comment: Yeah. Missed the grails version part. Thanks man..Will edit my answer.